# How can I get my gnome lockscreen as default instead of the grey system one?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, kali-linux, desktop-environment

Suddenly my lockscreen changed from the gnome (blue one) lockscreen that detects the username and asks for password to the login screen that asks for both username and password. I am trying to get it back, but nothing is working.

[image: Gnome lockscreen]

[image: New login screen]

I found this at the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file:

```
Start-Date: 2020-10-18  08:28:59
Commandline: apt install kali-defaults kali-root-login desktop-base xfce4 xfce4-places-plugin xfce4-goodies
Requested-By: username (1000)
Install: xfburn:amd64 (0.6.2-1, automatic), libisofs6:amd64 (1.5.2-1, automatic), thunar-media-tags-plugin:amd64 (0.3.0-2, automatic), xfce4-dict:amd64 (0.8.3-1, automatic), xfce4-goodies:amd64 (4.14.0), xfce4-terminal:amd64 (0.8.9.2-1, automatic), libburn4:amd64 (1.5.2-1, automatic), kali-root-login:amd64 (2019.4.0), libjte2:amd64 (1.22-3, automatic)
Upgrade: kali-defaults:amd64 (2020.3.4, 2020.4.2)
End-Date: 2020-10-18  08:29:56
```

Comment: Looks like your PC may have updated. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It was a system update, I guess gnome was updated too

Comment: As a suggestion, [you could check](https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/basic-troubleshooting/) `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see whether the screensaver packages were changed by an upgrade.

Comment: I found only one command entry in the `history.log` file installing some packages, recheck the post